# Meteor: Bind function to work for every iteration of template

Tags: templates, meteor

I'm fairly new to Meteor and I can't get my head around how to get a function to work in every iteration of a template independently from the others. I've written a very basic function where I want to display a pop up inside each template on button click, but the pop up always appears at the first generated template instead of being bound to the specific button I click. I've searched around and found that it might have to do with template instances or reactive variables but as of now I'm rather confused. 
Could this be on the right track? https://dweldon.silvrback.com/template-instance

My code:

.html

```
<body>
  {{> test}}
</body>

<template name="test">
  {{#each tasks}}
    <button type="button" id="popup">Click Me!</button>
    <div id="pops">Hi</div>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

.js

```
Tasks = new Mongo.Collection("tasks");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.test.helpers({
    tasks: function () {
      return Tasks.find({});
    }
  });

  Template.test.events({
    'click #popup': function(e, template) {
      template.$('#pops').fadeIn();
    }
  });
}
```

I haven't written anything in the server code at all.
Thanks!

Comment: for example, if you have 5 tasks, every task will get the same button id `popup` and div `pops`. Thus events cant decide which `button` is being clicked.

Comment: I get that, but shouldn't the id be tied to the template somehow? Because I'm still calling the function inside the template. It is not template.body.events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Don't use IDs, use classes instead. Why? Because you are not allowed to have several elements with the same ID.
2. Create new template `task` and render it inside `each` loop.

HTML:

```
<body>
  {{> test}}
</body>

<template name="test">
  {{#each tasks}}
    {{> task}}
  {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="task">
  <button type="button" class="popup">Click Me!</button>
  <div class="pops">Hi</div>
</template>
```

JS:

```
Template.task.events({
  'click .popup': function() {
    template.$('.pops').fadeIn();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing your code like this

```
<template name="test">
{{#each tasks}}
<button type="button">Click Me!</button>
<div id={{_id}}>Hi</div>
{{/each}}
</template>

Template.test.events({
'click button': function(e, template) {
var id = '#'+this._id;
$(id).fadeIn();
}
});
}
```

Comment: It didn't work, sorry. Thanks though! I've managed before to access the independent data from each elements inside a template so the problem is to access a unique id for the pop up where the id is tied to the template it is current in. It guess it has to do something with the scope. So I understand what you intend to do but to my mind there should be a more "obvious" solution.