# Using method calls in Meteor js inside a template

Tags: templates, meteor, methods

I'm trying to insert the current logged in users id into an array in a specific document in a collection in meteor. I'm doing this by calling a method from the server. For the most part this works just fine except for one thing, the users id should be inserted in the current template where the button is clicked. I'm building a "meets gathering" system where the user should apply to join a specific meet. So the users id should be inserted in every meet they attend to.

Client:

```
Template.eventcard.events({
    'click .applynow': function(){
        Meteor.call('updatemeetswithuser');
    }
});
```

Server code:

```
Meteor.methods({
    updatemeetswithuser: function(){
        Meets.update({_str: this._str}, {$push:{users : this.userId}});
    }
});
```

The _str: this_str works because I have inserted it so that it is a mongo collection and not meteor collection. The problem, however, is that the users id:s are always inserted in the first and same document in my {{#each }} loop regardless of in which template the button is clicked and not tied to each template as I want it to.

Yesterday I asked a somewhat similar question here: [Meteor: Bind function to work for every iteration of template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34176740/meteor-bind-function-to-work-for-every-iteration-of-template) where I could tie every function to a specific template independently from each other, I don't know if this has to do with something similar or not but maybe it can help.

So I guess what I need to do is via a method get the id of the template somehow. Thanks, any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need  to pass some parameter to update the right record otherwise you will always update the same record so your method should look like:

```
Meteor.methods({
  updatemeetswithuser: function(meetId){
    Meets.update({_id: meetId}, {$push:{users : this.userId}});
  }
});
```

I admit my ignorance but I don't know what is this._str and I didn't find a clear documentation on it. It seems mongo default id, but I don't think you really need if you are developing all the app with meteor .

In client obviously you have to pass the right id to the method.

```
Template.eventcard.events({
  'click .applynow': function(){
    var meetId = ...; //save in your html or find another solution to get meetId
    Meteor.call('updatemeetswithuser',meetId);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks this is great, saved my day! To get the id I simply did var meetId = this._id :)